# Overwriting mongo document in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a whole document using mongoose.

```
myModel.update({_id:item._id}, item, {overwrite: true});
```

I found out that by using `overwrite` option a document can be overwritten instead of only updating the fields in mongoose object. (Strange thing is that, mongo's default behaviour is overwriting)

The problem is that when I try to update a document where a `Date` field is removed, I am getting `Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined` error. I believe this is happening because in my schema the removed field is defined as `Date` and mongoose throw exception while converting undefined to `Date`. So I am confused how can I update a document where a date field is optional.
So let's say my original document is:

```
{_id: id, startDate: myDate, title: "title"}
```

When I try to update the document to following I am getting the exception:

```
{_id: id, title: "title"}
```

Basically my question is how can I overwrite a document where a date field is optional, so a document might be created with a date field, but that might be removed in the future.

Comment: It worked fine when I tried it. Make sure `item` is a plain object and not a Mongoose model instance.

Comment: it's a plain javascript object, which version of mongooes you are using? I am using 3.8.12

Comment: This was with 3.8.19. Can you add your schema definition to your question?

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK, after updating to 3.8.20 it started working.

Answer (score 0):

have You tried to use this.save or smth like this?